# Sparse 3D matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, sparse-matrix

I am using Matlab. I have a 3d rgb histogram which stores the number of pixels per `(r, g, b)` value. The 3d matrix is extremely sparse. Is there any way to deal with a sparse 3d Matrix in Matlab? I will be obliged.

Comment: Could you explain what is '3d rgb histogram'? Maybe, do you mean histogram with one bar per color?

Comment: the rgb histogram has red, green and blue (each from 0-255) plotted as x, y and z axes. I have an image. The number of pixels for each (r,g,b) value are plotted in the space. Think of it as a cube which contains some points. But much of the cube is empty. I want to know if there is a way to shrink the cube without losing useful data.

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: You could try to increase the size of the bins in the histogram.

Comment: What are you going to be using the histogram for?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question was not very clear, so I have reformulated it to make it more understandable, searchable and useful. I'm now answering your question to remove it from the unanswered list.

As known, Matlab does not directly deal with 3D matrices. A workaround is using cell arrays of sparse matrices.

Suppose that you want to create a sparse matrix containing only the elements `(1, 1, 1)` and `(1, 3, 50)` and suppose that `A(1, 1, 1) = 1` and `A(1, 3, 10) = 54`. You can do the following:

```
mySp{1}  = sparse(3, 3);
mySp{10} = sparse(3, 3);

mySp{1}(1, 1) = 3;
mySp{10}(1, 3) = 54;
```

In this way,

```
>> mySp

mySp = 

    [3x3 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    [3x3 double]
```

As it can be seen, `mySp` is an array of `10` elements. The first and the tenth elements are sparse matrices, while the others are empty. The non-empty first and tenth sparse matrices can be recovered as

```
temp1 = mySp{1};
temp2 = mySp{10};
```

returning

```
>> temp1

temp1 =

   (1,1)        3
```

and

```
temp2 =

   (1,3)       54
```